# How to write mysql sub query in CDbCriteria and CActiveDataProvider in yii?

Tags: yii

example :

```
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT * 
       FROM `servicelist` `t` 
       WHERE t.is_accept_by_driver = 0 ) as tmp GROUP BY servicenumber
```

Comment: Is that the full query? That query does not make much sense (especially using subquery) for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\Yii::app()
  ->db
  ->createCommand(
      "SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT * 
       FROM `servicelist` `t` 
       WHERE t.is_accept_by_driver = 0 ) as tmp GROUP BY servicenumber"
      )
  ->queryAll()
```